# how to consume backend services in maximo anywhere mobile app

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I would like to know how we can consume web services in maximo anywhere apps. Currently im accessing static data from javascript files.Please help with sample code.

Answer (score -1):

Webservice can be invoked using the Javascript adapters which are deployed on the server. The javascript methods in the mobile-app will invoke the methods in the adapter which in turn invokes the methods in the backend.

Sample code can be found in the below URL.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/javascript-adapters/js-http-adapter/#creatingSoapServiceRequest